# Can I use arduino to feed this circuit instead of an external power source?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, battery-operated

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/?ALLSTEPS) to connect the output from my guitar with arduino.

I'm wondering: is it possible not to use the batteries, and to feed the circuit with the 5V output pin provided by arduino?

I guess that I would have to use a different operational amplifier, but I don't know how to choose it and how to, eventually, change the other components. I found some other amplifiers which need a lower voltage supply (instead of the one used in the tutorial) but I am not able to understand how different features of that component would affect the entire circuit's work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend as a first step building up the original circuit using something like http://everycircuit.com/ to get an 'intuition' for how it works. As long as the Arduino has enough power at its output pin (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=121675.0) this source says 5V and 20ma then you *could* try and design an new circuit with a boost converter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter to step up to whatever voltages you need. If you are not experienced with circuit design I would try and stick to the original design as much as possible - just replacing the battery section with an op-amp section and leaving everything else the same. Here is a good introduction to op-amps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3RMFpGGcZM.

This may work out well - it really depends on the specifics of the actual set of components you are going to use. The datasheets of the components will have voltage and power ratings. I don't see why it would not be possible on one hand but I don't have a working design that I have carefully simulated.

I hope that this is helpful!
Good luck :)